# adding the specific flow name in log4j2 when using mule

Tags: logging, mule, esb, log4j2, anypoint-studio

I am setting up a SMTP appender with log4j2 to use in mule and I would like to include the name of the flow that the error has come from in the email.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default layout for the SMTP Appender is the [HTML Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#HTMLLayout). This layout has a title attribute. What you can try is to embed a [ThreadContext map lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#ContextMapLookup) in the title attribute. For example, `title="$${ctx:flow}"`.

In PatternLayout, you can achieve the same by embedding `%X{flow}` in the pattern.

In your Java code, you would call `ThreadContext.put("flow", "someValue");`
and all following logging in that thread would have that value for "flow".

Comment: we are using the pattern layout for the smtp appender and we don't have java code, we have the mule flows and the log4j2.xml

Comment: Updated for PatternLayout. Not sure how Mule works, but something will need to set the key-value pair in the ThreadContext. Will Mule not allow you to run custom logic?

Answer (score 0):

The MEL expression #[flow.name] will give you the name of the current flow.  This can be used directly or in a parse Template to build your message body.